# alert() stops the background music on the page

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm creating a web game that uses a soundtrack in the background and I use alert() to show important massages to the user.
But after alert is shown the music stops and it's really annoying. Tried using

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('hello world'); }, 1);
```

as a solution when I browsed stackoverflow but it doesnt work with music apparently. Is there any way to prevent that? Or maybe there is an alternative to alert that I dont know about?
If it's worth mentioning im playing music via audio tag and calling it by idname.play().

Comment: Yep, the alert stop de sound. You may use a modal for show an alert. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @Roy a funny thing is, that `alert` actually shows a modal window, and bootstrap modals are less modal, almost modeless ...

Comment: modals are a lot of extra code in my already crowded files. So there isnt any simpler solution?

Comment: I'm also not really sure how I would trigger those modals. I fire alerts after user clicks on a div with opacity 0 so doing this by modals looks like a nightmare

Comment: @MattiMazur It's not very complicated to implement a simple modal. Here's one I just threw together: http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/xgoeEV

Comment: Yeah, i know. But extra code for a better solution is ok. And to open a modal you just have to add an attribute like data-modal="#modalName" and that is all.

Comment: But when you need around 30 modals its becoming a mess in a file. Thank you for your answers, but I think I will just stick to the alert(). Modals are not really hard to implement, but multiple modals are a pain.